# Use of compound literal inside a function to init a variable in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct, compound-literals

This question follows this one : [Is there a syntax in C to DIRECTLY INIT a struct member that is a const array of constant literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78141912/7462275).

Eric Postpischil gave me a solution using compound literals.

Now, I would like to initialise my variables in a function. But, inside a function, compound literal has automatic storage duration and datas are needed outside this function. To solve this problem, I used the `static` keyword but I am not sure that is a good idea.

This is the initial code (with initialisation in the main)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  const char* name;
  const int nb;
  const char* const* list;
} valid_options_t;

void print_options (const valid_options_t* option) {
  printf("Option Name : %s\n",option->name);
  for (int i=0; i < option->nb; i++) printf("\t%s\n",option->list[i]);
  printf("---------\n");
}
int main() {

  const valid_options_t my_size_opts = {.name="size", .nb=3, .list= (const char * const[]) {"large", "medium", "small"} };
  const valid_options_t my_color_opts = {.name="color", .nb=4, .list= (const char * const[]) {"orange", "yellow", "white", "red"} };
  const valid_options_t my_form_opts = {.name="shape", .nb=2, .list= (const char * const[]) {"circle", "square"} };

  print_options (&my_size_opts);
  print_options (&my_color_opts);
  print_options (&my_form_opts);

}
```

And the code with initialisation in a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  const char* name;
  const int nb;
  const char* const* list;
} valid_options_t;

void print_options (const valid_options_t* option) {
  printf("Option Name : %s\n",option->name);
  for (int i=0; i < option->nb; i++) printf("\t%s\n",option->list[i]);
  printf("---------\n");
}

void init_coumpond_literal(valid_options_t *(*my_opts)[3]) {
  (*my_opts)[0] = &(static valid_options_t){.name="size", .nb=3, .list= (static const char * const[]) {"large", "medium", "small"} };
  (*my_opts)[1] = &(static valid_options_t){.name="color", .nb=4, .list= (static const char * const[]) {"orange", "yellow", "white", "red"} };
  (*my_opts)[2] = &(static valid_options_t){.name="shape", .nb=2, .list= (static const char * const[]) {"circle", "square"} };
}

int main() {

  const int feature_nb=3;
  
  valid_options_t *my_size_opts[feature_nb];
  
  init_coumpond_literal(&my_size_opts);
  
  for (int i=0; i < feature_nb; i++)
    print_options (my_size_opts[i]);
}
```

Is it the right way to do that ? And how can I free these variables ?

Comment: Obviously you cannot free static objects.

Comment: @IanAbbott. I know that. And this is my problem. So that is why I wonder if it is the right way to that.

Comment: By the way, use of storage class specifiers such as `static` in a compound literal is only allowed in C23 onwards which is not yet a published standard.

Comment: @Ian Abbot. Are there some others specifiers ?

Comment: One improvement may be to declare `my_size_opts` as `const valid_options_t *my_size_opts[feature_nb];` and make corresponding changes to the parameters of `init_compound_literal` and `print_options` and the compound literals.

Comment: If you don't want to rely of C23 features, you could replace the static compound literals with static variables (or a static array). Any compound literals used in the initialization of the static variable or static array element will automatically be given static storage duration.

Comment: I'm sure you already know, but it's worth mentioning, there are thread safety issues regarding use of static variables. What's a 'coumpond'_literal? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code is fine for C23, which is yet to be published at the time of writing, but for portability to earlier C standards, the `static` qualifier needs to be removed from the compound literals, but then they would no longer have static storage duration as required, so another solution would be required. One possibility is to replace the compound literals with static variables of limited scope, for example:

```
#define ARRAYLEN(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))
```

```
void init_coumpond_literal(valid_options_t *(*my_opts)[3]) {
  static const char * const list_size[] = {"large", "medium", "small"};
  static const char * const list_color[] = {"orange", "yellow", "white", "red"};
  static const char * const list_shape[] = {"circle", "square"};
  static valid_options_t opts[3] = {
    {.name="size", .nb=ARRAYLEN(list_size), .list=list_size },
    {.name="color", .nb=ARRAYLEN(list_color), .list=list_color },
    {.name="shape", .nb=ARRAYLEN(list_shape), .list=list_shape }
  };
  (*my_opts)[0] = &opts[0];
  (*my_opts)[1] = &opts[1];
  (*my_opts)[2] = &opts[2];
}
```

EDIT: Removed non-constant static initializers for `.list` members in the above and replaced with more static variables. Thanks to **Eric Postpischil** for pointing out the error.

The above initialization of `opts` could be simplified by defining a temporary macro:

```
void init_coumpond_literal(valid_options_t *(*my_opts)[3]) {
  static const char * const list_size[] = {"large", "medium", "small"};
  static const char * const list_color[] = {"orange", "yellow", "white", "red"};
  static const char * const list_shape[] = {"circle", "square"};
  static valid_options_t opts[3] = {
#define XOPT(x) { .name=#x, .nb=ARRAYLEN(list_##x), .list=list_##x } 
    XOPT(size),
    XOPT(color),
    XOPT(shape)
#undef XOPT
  };
  (*my_opts)[0] = &opts[0];
  (*my_opts)[1] = &opts[1];
  (*my_opts)[2] = &opts[2];
}
```

The `opts` array is modifiable outside the function because it is not `const`. If that is undesirable, declare `opts` as `static const valid_options_t opts[3] = …;`, and make appropriate changes elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Both GCC and Clang complain that `(const char * const[]) {"large", "medium", "small"}` is not constant (GCC) or a compile-time constant (Clang). Using a compound literal in the initialization of a static object does not make give it static storage duration. In C 2018, if a compound literal appears inside the body of a function, it has automatic storage duration.

Comment: I got the same error with gcc. But I keep my C23 version because it works with gcc and I suppose the standard will be published very soon. Right ?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks. I corrected it by replacing the compound literal arrays with static array variables, which also has the advantage of being able to determine the number of elements of those arrays programatically using the `sizeof` trick.

Comment: @Stef1611 Hopefully it will be published in 2024 based on previous history. Then there will be the eternal debate on whether to call it C23 or C24, cf. C17 vs. C18.

Answer (score 1):

when using static within the init_coumpound_literal function creates objects with static storage duration, it's not ideal in this case. why:

Memory Leaks: The function creates static objects and assigns their addresses to my_size_opts, but there's no way to free the memory. This leads to a memory leak.

Readability: The code becomes less readable due to the use of nested pointers and double indirection.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Concerning readability, I agree but nested pointers, double indirection are often used. So it is not really a problem for me. Concerning Memory Leaks, see my comments to Ian Abbot in the question.

Comment: There is no memory leak.