# How to set a pointer to an integer in a compound literal that is initialized in a function?

Tags: c, struct, compound-literals, c23

I tried to initialise a structure via a compound literal in a function. After solving a part of my problem (see [Use of compound literal inside a function to init a variable in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78159603/7462275)), I have a new problem with one member (`ptr_mb`) that must be a pointer to a variable.

This is the code:

```
typedef struct {
  int i_mb;
  int * ptr_mb;
} my_struct_t;

void init_struct(my_struct_t **my_struct, int * const ptr) {
  *my_struct=&(static my_struct_t) {.i_mb=3, .ptr_mb= ptr};
}

int main() {
  int a;
  my_struct_t *my_struct;
  
  // my_struct = &(my_struct_t) {.i_mb=3, .ptr_mb=&a}; It is OK

  // Try to initialize it in a function
  init_struct(&my_struct, &a);
  
}
```

In `main()`, it works (cf commented line in the program)

A compilation error was emitted. In the function `init_struct`, *ptr is not a constant* (line : `*my_struct=&(static my_struct_t) {.i_mb=3, .ptr_mb= ptr};`).

`a` is a variable declared in `main()`. Thus, its address is constant. I tried to cast the affectation with `(int const *)`, `(int * const)`, `(int const * const)`, .... Sometimes it was nonsense, but just to try and nothing worked.

Is it possible to do such initialisation in a function, the way it works in `main()`?

(Rq. `static` is used. I know it is a C23 standard and that standard is not yet published; for detail, see this answer: [Use of compound literal inside a function to init a variable in C](/a/78159921/7462275).)

Comment: @Eugene.Sh. It is only a part of the problem. I need the static (cf the remark a the end and the link )

Comment: I don't see how it applies in your case. You merely want a field-wise copy from the compound literal, and you don't need it to be of `static` lifetime.

Comment: Re “`a` variable is a variable declared in the `main`. Thus, its address is constant.”: No, it is not. `a` names an object with automatic storage duration. Memory is reserved for it when the function’s block starts execution. Even if you can predict where that memory will be for the initial call to `main`, C allows calling `main` recursively, so the `a` for such a call will be at some other address. The reason initialization using `&a` is accepted in `main` is because you have an automatic compound literal initializing an automatic object (`my_struct`), which do not require constants.

Comment: The type of `*my_struct` is `my_struct_t`. The type of `&(static my_struct_t) {.i_mb=3, .ptr_mb= ptr};` is `my_struct_t *`. Which one you want?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI. Exact. Version error. I edit my code. But the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: What is the expectation if there are two consecutive calls to `init_struct` with different parameters?

Comment: You cannot have a static literal contain non-constant data. Don't use a static literal, and don't initialize a pointer. Use an automatic literal, and initialize a struct. If you need a pointer to a struct, take the address of the struct you just initialized.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI *You cannot have a static literal contain non-constant data* - well, you can, but can't have it in the initializer, as the initialization only happens once. But I agree that it looks like an XY-problem.

Comment: @Eric Postpischi. Thanks for comment. If I do not call `main` recursively, can I be sure that address of `a` will not change ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for comment. `init_struct` is only called once. So it is not a problem to keep it in the main. I wrote a function to split the code.

Comment: Then you should simply define `static my_struct_t my_struct = {3, NULL}` and then `my_struct.ptr_mb = &a`. Or make the field-wise initialization in a separate function if you wish. I do not understand what you are trying to do otherwise.

Comment: @Stef1611 For what are you going to use all these `my_struct_t` pointers that points at the same element, containing values set by the last initialized pointer?

Comment: @Ted Lyngno. It is just a short example to sum up my problem. Very long to explain. I will post my code in code review when it is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do not do it during the initialisation. Add one assignment.

```
typedef struct {
  int i_mb;
  int * ptr_mb;
} my_struct_t;

void init_struct(my_struct_t **my_struct, int * const ptr) {
  *my_struct = &(static my_struct_t){.i_mb=3};
  (*my_struct) -> ptr_mb = ptr;
}

int a = 10;
int main() {

  my_struct_t *my_struct;
  
  // Try to initialize it in a function
  init_struct(&my_struct, &a);  

  /* ... */ 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. It works (gcc is used). But, the answer of Lundin worries me.

Comment: @Stef1611  My solution is 100% portable and you do not have to worry as the assignment is done when the function is called and it is done after main and it is not an initalization.

Comment: @Stef1611 It is OK, although the shared, static storage will get modified each time `init_struct()` is called, which *might* be a problem if it is called several times with different `ptr` values and previous incarnations are still in use.

Comment: @gulpr. I used your answer in the full program. It works perfectly. Thanks a lot !!!!!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work for the same reason as this doesn't work:

```
int main()
{
  int a;
  static int* ptr = &a;
}
```

One has to realize that initialization of static storage duration variables happens *before* `main()` is called and not at the line where the declaration is located. And since `a` has automatic storage duration, it doesn't have an address until  `main()` is called. On mainstream systems, `a` gets allocated on the stack at that point.

---

The next thing we have to realize is that it doesn't matter if `a` has a fixed address, not even if we change it to `static int a;`. Because `int * const ptr` is not an *address constant*, which is a formal term for a certain type of constant expression. C23 6.6:

> An *address constant* is a null pointer, a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static storage duration, or a pointer to a function designator; it shall be created explicitly using the unary & operator or an integer constant cast to pointer type, or implicitly using an expression of array or function type.

Now wait a minute... `int a` in main() or `&a` is none of the above either. So the line

```
my_struct = &(my_struct_t) {.i_mb=3, .ptr_mb=&a}; // It is OK
```

is actually *not* OK either. The code works because of implementation-defined extensions in gcc/clang, but it is not strictly conforming C and not portable.

Comment: Thanks for this very interesting answer. Is there a link to learn and to understand the `implementation-defined extensions in gcc/clang` ?

Comment: If I understand : the static storage in the function `init_struct` happens before the call to main. Right ?

Comment: @Stef1611 No links except various arguments I've had with the gcc crew about this at Bugzilla. The problem isn't so much that gcc (and clang) allows implementation-defined constant expressions, but that they silently let them through in `-pedantic` mode, making it impossible to test if one's code is strictly conforming or not. Older gcc versions weren't as tolerant, though they always accepted address constants from objects with automatic storage duration, apparently.

Comment: @Stef1611 Regarding the second comment: yes.